# How to handle LongPressed event of a Zebble view or control

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

How can I subscribe to **LongPressed**  event of a Zebble view like the following ImageView?

```
 <ImageView on-LongPressed="@ViewLongPressed"  on-Tapped="@ViewTapped"   />
```

I can handle **on-tapped** event with following method but doing the same do not work when I hold the left mouse button **for a few** seconds or clicking with middle **mouse button** .

```
 public async Task ViewTapped() =>
                await Nav.ShowPopUp<Pages.ListPage>(new { Item = Item });
```

Is it possible to trigger this event in the UWP simulator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Long pressed event in (desktop) windows is fired by a single right click.